# Unable to install 64-bit Oracle 10g Release 2 ODAC 10.2.0.3 for Windows x64 on 64 bit Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: oracle

I need to connect an application to Oracle. In the installation guide for that application it says that it requires 64 bit version of Oracle Data Access Component,more specifically 10.2.0.3 . I have tried installing it but I am continuously getting the error attached in the image when ever I try running the installer. The crash details are given in the image attached. Has some one ever tried installing it? If yes then would it be possible to give some details or point me in the right direction so that I can complete this installation.

[image]
[image]
Thanks

Comment: apparently others have experienced something similar. https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=706071

Answer (score 1):

I think That version of ODAC is not certified on Windows 2008 R2. Please use the regular Oracle DB Client that supports Windows 2008 R2. If you need to use ODP.NET 10.2, then go here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/10204-winx64-vista-win2k8-082253.html

It can be very helpful to You.